# Error when using ActionMailer in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-3-upgrade

Currently i'm trying to port my application to Rails 3.0 from 2.3.14 and I'm struck on the following error and this works fine in 2.3.14

My mailer code looks like

```
def welcome_mail(host,vendor_name,from, batch, sent_at = Time.now)
  template = MailTemplate.get_template(self.class.to_s,:welcome_mail.to_s,vendor_name,
              :greeting => batch.greeting, :batch => batch, :host =>host)
  @html_message = template.html_message
  @text_message = template.text_message
  mail( :subject => batch.subject, :to => get_recipients(batch), :from =>  from, :date =>  sent_at ) do |format|
    format.html
    format.text
  end
end
```

I pick up the email content from DB using MailTemplate model.

And my mailer view (welcome_mail.text.html.erb and welcome_mail.text.plain.erb contain only this line

```
<%=@html_message%> - welcome_mail.text.html.erb
<%=@text_message%> - welcome_mail.text.plain.erb
```

Inside the template, that is fetched from DB, i'm using a named route (which is a nested route) profile_batch_url and is supposed to produce a url like /profile/:profile_id/batch/:batch_id

But when I try to create a message

```
mail = UserMailer.welcome_email(request.host_with_port,get_vendor_name(),email, batch)
```

I'm getting the following error

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `controller' for #<MailTemplate:0x000000060dff38>
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activemodel-3.0.17/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:392:in `method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.0.17/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:46:in `method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-3.0.17/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:31:in `url_options'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-3.0.17/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:131:in `url_for'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-3.0.17/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:99:in `url_for'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-3.0.17/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:201:in `profile_batch_url'
(erb):5:in `text_message'
```

Can anyone help me in fixing this?

Thanks,
Sivakumar

Comment: What is the MailTemplate class?

Comment: mail_templates is the table from which the mail content is retrieved. MailTemplate is the corresponding model class.

Comment: Do you have anything in that model that references a controller?

Comment: No. It just fetches the template based on some fields we pass in.